# Flexbox overlapping absoluted positioned childrens

Tags: css, css-position, flexbox, z-index, absolute

I got a problem with `flexbox` containers with absolute positioned childrens.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jcgyce3g/1/); if the window getting smaller (in width) the titles getting smaller, what is absolutly correct, the problem is in the digits that are overlapping over the other watches. I tested a bit around with `z-Index`, `background-color` but doesn't get anything work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="stopwatch">
    <div class="stopwatch__panel">
        <div class="stopwatch__header">
            <div class="stopwatch__title">Random Title 404531</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stopwatch__body">
            <div class="stopwatch__counter">
                <div class="stopwatch__segment stopwatch__segment--five">
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTopLeft"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTop"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTopRight"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddle">
                        <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddleTop"></div>
                        <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddleBottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottomLeft"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottom"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottomRight"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="stopwatch__segment stopwatch__segment--five">
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTopLeft"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTop"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTopRight"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddle">
                        <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddleTop"></div>
                        <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddleBottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottomLeft"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottom"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottomRight"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stopwatch__panel">
        <div class="stopwatch__header">
            <div class="stopwatch__title">Random Title 714895</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stopwatch__body">
            <div class="stopwatch__counter">
                <div class="stopwatch__segment stopwatch__segment--nine">
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTopLeft"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTop"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentTopRight"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddle">
                        <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddleTop"></div>
                        <div class="stopwatch__segmentMiddleBottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottomLeft"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottom"></div>
                    <div class="stopwatch__segmentBottomRight"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.stopwatch {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.stopwatch__panel {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    min-width: 0;
}

.stopwatch__header {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    order: 1;
}

.stopwatch__title {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.stopwatch__body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.stopwatch__counter {
    background-color: #333333;
    padding: 15px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.stopwatch__segment {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 6px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 35px;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.stopwatch__segment--zero .stopwatch__segmentTopRight {
    border-right-color: #e6e6e6;
}
/* [...all numbers from zero to nine... (only coloring borders) ] */
.stopwatch__segment--nine .stopwatch__segmentBottom {
    border-bottom-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.stopwatch__segmentTop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    height: 0;
    width: 10px;
    border-top: 3px solid #424242;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.stopwatch__segmentTopRight {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 3px solid #424242;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
/* [... the other segments parts ...] */
```

[image: Example with more digits]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting to have happen. Absolute positioning is going to do what it does. I'm not sure what flexbox can do to change that,

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know where the problem comes from, flexbox or the absolute positioning. Don't you see the overlapping (the image) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow:hidden;` to   `.stopwatch__counter`

```
.stopwatch__counter {
    background-color: #333333;
    padding: 15px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    overflow:hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; }
```

see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/jcgyce3g/2/

Comment: I think, I lost the overview! I additionally changed the `width` from `.stopwatch_segment` to `min-width` Thank you! +1